# is there a way to register an intent that reacts to specific voice searches?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Based on this answer:
[Android - Intent for custom voice action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185975/android-intent-for-custom-voice-action)

I see that what I'm looking for doesn't appear to exist yet (though if it now does, I'd LOVE to know how to use it).

Can anyone in the know (at Google) chime in with whether such functionality  is in the works? Specifically, the ability to register your app in an Intent(ish) way to bind to specific voice keywords, so that when the voice recognition engine hears "MY SPECIFIC KEYWORD" it knows to offer the user my app as an end point to handling the rest of the voice request.

TIA

Comment: Some people would consider this a step towards that dystopian society we see in movies like "V for Vendetta" :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Nobody knows.

It's a little bit strange to use StackOverflow for ETA on future Android releases.

Since 2007, None of the Android feature or API as been announced before the official release!

So, the answer to your question is simply: No, there is no chime about such features in the works, and if it was the case, this does not belong here.

Comment: yeah... I was sort of hoping that the answer would have been "yeah, that's totally a new feature in JB!", which is why I decided to post it here.  I agree that as a general query about when/if it's in the works, this isn't the best forum for that.

Comment: Best place to look is here I think: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html