# Launch an Android App from Google Voice Search

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Thanks for taking the time to help me out :)

### Topic

Android application development for a home automation application.

### Scenario

When I swipe upwards on the HOME button, the Google Voice Search screen is launched. I would like to speak a command such as "open window blinds" and have my application launch with the transcribed text. My application would then parse the command and open the window blinds.

### Problem

How do I launch my application when a certain phrase is spoken in the Google Voice Search window and send that application the spoken text?

**A similar question:** [Android - Intent for custom voice action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185975/android-intent-for-custom-voice-action)

**Similar to this video (except with Android):** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUJ5z76Xv5o&feature=share&list=PLnTLM_EQaoKogUJuTqeVtFB_O1pd0caic&index=2

Comment: I removed the `google-voice` tag. That tag is reserved for Google Voice, the telephone forwarding service that Google offers, not Google Now's voice recognition.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that!