# Custom actions for voice interaction on android

Tags: android, google-voice-actions

I am trying to make an application on Android that can interact with its user. And I came across [this](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/interaction/voice-interactions#handling_the_voice_interaction). The example in this link shows us that an interaction with the user can be done using the voice interaction service. My question is, can we add custom voice interactions which are application specific? like this "Send a Hangouts message to Bob" or "Start a Hangouts chat." I tired to search if this was possible and could not find anything [I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185975/android-intent-for-custom-voice-action) question but it is pretty old from the dates].